# Google Map Geocoding - Geocode on autosuggest click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am trying to optimize my geocoding script not that it actually works and I was wondering if it possible to actually initiate the geocode when a user selects an autosuggestion from the drop down.

This way the geocode will be complete by the time the user clicks the search button, and they wont have to wait. Is it possible to use some kind of event to trigger the geocode when the user clicks on an autosuggested location?

**This is the code**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/22/
```

**Raw Javascript**

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // SET COOKIE FOR TESTING   
    $.cookie("country", "UK");

    // GEOCODE RESULT
    function geocode() {

        var GeoCoded = {
            done: false
        };
        var input = document.getElementById('loc');
        var options = {
            types: ['geocode']
        };
        var country_code = $.cookie('country');
        if (country_code) {
            options.componentRestrictions = {
                'country': country_code
            };
        }
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
            if (GeoCoded.done) return true;
            e.preventDefault();
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('loc').value;
            $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            },

            function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    GeoCoded.done = true;
                    $.cookie("location_input", $("#loc").val());
                    $.cookie("lng", $("#lng").val());
                    $.cookie("lat", $("#lat").val());
                    $('#searchform').submit();
                } else {
                    $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
                    alert("We couldn't find this location")
                }

            });

        });

    };  
</script>


<body onload="geocode()">
    <form id="searchform">
        <input class="kw" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword"></input>
        <input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
        <input class="hidden" id="lat" disabled="true" placeholder="lat"></input>
        <input class="hidden" id="lng" disabled="true" placeholder="lng"></input>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind event handler to autocomplete's 'place_changed' event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
   //initiate the geocode
});
```

You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#Autocomplete)

Comment: That looks just what I am after, except I couldn't get it to work. For my example shouldn't it be something as simple as this? google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
geocode()
});

Comment: no, you are defining autocomplete inside geocode function, you can't bind event handler to it before its defined, I think you should put this event handler right after creating autocomplete and use same function that you apply on submitting searchform

Comment: I think your instructions are right, but I can't get it to work, I'm new to javascript and it seems like this stuff is a bit above me. This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/23/

Comment: as I said, you should use same code that you used on form submit.
I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/25/) - I separated out it into processLocation function and put it for both 'place_changed' and form sumbit

Comment: updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/26/) once more, its better to keep javascript code in javascript section there (it will be executed on window load), and add additinal resources as 'external resources'

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use the jQuery Autocomplete Widget and fetch the data from the Google as the source data for the jQuery Autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this cannot filter based on country, which is a real shame but it stops me being able to use it